# Javascript / HTML syntax format error

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

I have one line of code that I'm mixing JQuery / HTML but I think I have a syntax error somewhere around the `<a href` Can anyone spot the issue please?

Here is the code:

```
$("<div><a href="http://google.com>""+today+"</a></div>")
```

Comment: you have `"` inside `"`.

Comment: Are you being serious right now? I find it hard to believe that you would take all the time to post this question before checking the simplest of HTML syntax. SO even highlights the problem in your code. I can understand being confused between when to use `'` and when to use `"` - but your `href` url isn't enclosed in either!

Comment: It's a silly question, but I don't think it deserves a down vote, it's very easy for any JS developer to see the problem and help him out

Comment: Try using something like JSLint, it can force you to write cleaner, "syntactically safe" code. Run it manually (http://jslint.com/) or get a plugin for your IDE / text editor.

Comment: jlindenbaum: Thanks for the link to jslint.com. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Satch3000: It's not a matter of being `as smart` as me. It's a simple matter of basic HTML syntax. If you don't know HTML syntax, you really shouldn't even be touching javascript yet. It's a little bit like driving your car into a mechanic - only the car has no wheels, seats, or engine - and you ask "Can you tell me why my car won't drive?" Technically, that's what the mechanic is for ... but I'd bet you still get a weird look.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('<div><a href="http://google.com">' + today + '</a></div>');
```

Alternate:

```
$("<div><a href=\"http://google.com\">" + today + "</a></div>");
```

Quotes wrapped in quotes of the same type need to be escaped with a backslash.

You also needed the quotes to wrap the href value correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Your leading double quote is cancelling out your href= double quote.

```
$('<div><a href="link">' + today + '</a></div>');
```